# Convert date in string to Date changing format in C

Tags: c, date

I need to parse a string like this:

```
Apr 3, 2014 10:03:51 AM
```

to something like this:

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
```

And also, this long long:

```
1396682344000
```

To the same kind of string:

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
```

Is there any library or function to do that? I am not very confortable writing C and I am not used to parse this kind of strings.

I tried with strptime with this code:

observationDate_message is the like first string (Apr 3, 2014 10:45:01 AM)

```
strptime(observationDate_message, "%G-%m-%d %r", &result);
    debugLog(DEB_INFO, "observationDateConverted: %d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d\n", result.tm_year, result.tm_mon, result.tm_mday, result.tm_hour, result.tm_min, result.tm_sec);
```

And what I get is:

```
0-52-0 36905376:32630:1497284224
```

Tutorial in; http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Frtref%2Fstrpti.htm

Comment: Why don't you search for date time functions in C ?

Comment: what is that number 1396682344000?

Comment: it i a date. It is called expiration date. but I don't have access to sender code. I think maybe it is a count of seconds from the starting date.

Comment: It looks like a unix time stamp in microseconds around two days from now. To get that one right you really need to use a proper time library to get leap seconds right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check if your system has the function `strptime`. It's part of POSIX and will do the parsing of the string for you. To convert in the opposite direction there's the C standard function `strftime`.

Comment: My system has it but I have a problem. I updated my question with that

Comment: Well, it looks like your format string to `strptime` has completely different layout than the string you actually pass in. It probably returned an error that you didn't check.

Answer (score 1):

you can parse

```
Apr 3, 2014 10:03:51 AM
```

this string using `sscanf()` and get the year month date and time information.
if `str` contains the string,

```
sscanf(str,"%s %d, %d %d:%d:%d AM",month,&dd,&yy,&hh,&mm,&ss);
```

you can get the data from string. This is just a example you can extract formatted data from string as you want using `sscanf()`

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to implement your own time parsing. Time is really complicated and should be left to libraries where someone has put in the decades necessary to understand all problems with time zones, different calendars, leap seconds, different time standards, etc. Please don't roll your own time handling, you will not get it right for a long time and when you do your code will be as complex as the library you didn't use.

Comment: by that, you refers to the use of sscanf?

Comment: I fully support *Art*'s statement. If you have `strptime()` avaliable do use it! Do not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I will check. Do you know how can I do that? I have access to a ssh connection so I can execute anything. Working on linux

Comment: @Art- come on, it'll work fine, up until Feb 28 2016 at least!

Comment: The question is about parsing the string? not about getting the time? Or is there something missing? except that 2nd part of question 1396682344000?

Comment: @Biribu You definitely have `strptime` on Linux. type `man strptime`